# PyLint in Eclpise, stop linting python runtime

Tags: python, eclipse, pylint

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

installed pylint with:

```
sudo apt-get install pylint
```

i downloaded eclipse luna and installed pydev over the marketplace. But instead of linting my code, my python runtime is linted.

My console output:

```
PyLint: Executing command line: /usr/bin/pylint /home/devnull/pyworkspace/soup/test1.py
PyLint: The stdout of the command line is: 
PyLint: The stderr of the command line is:   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 182
    file=sys.stderr)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My config:

[image: pylint eclipse]

Any idea what I configured wrong ?
If i run pylint from the terminal everything works fine.

**Update** my output from the terminal:

```
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module test1
C: 14, 0: Line too long (104/80) (line-too-long)
C: 14, 0: Exactly one space required after comma
    return  "{0}_{1}.html".format(date.today().strftime('%y_%m_%d'),         str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','_'))
                                                                                                      ^ (bad-whitespace)
C: 25, 0: Line too long (112/80) (line-too-long)
C: 37, 0: Exactly one space required after comma
with codecs.open(os.path.join(path,filename()),'w',encoding='utf8') as f:
                                  ^ (bad-whitespace)
C: 37, 0: Exactly one space required after comma
with codecs.open(os.path.join(path,filename()),'w',encoding='utf8') as f:
                                              ^ (bad-whitespace)
C: 37, 0: Exactly one space required after comma
with codecs.open(os.path.join(path,filename()),'w',encoding='utf8') as f:
                                                  ^ (bad-whitespace)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
F:  3, 0: Unable to import 'bs4' (import-error)
F: 10, 0: Unable to import 'selenium' (import-error)
F: 11, 0: Unable to import 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys' (import-error)
C: 13, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
C: 16, 0: Invalid constant name "path" (invalid-name)
C: 21, 0: Invalid constant name "driver" (invalid-name)
C: 30, 0: Invalid constant name "content" (invalid-name)
C: 33, 0: Invalid constant name "soup" (invalid-name)
W: 53,-1: String statement has no effect (pointless-string-statement)
W: 11, 0: Unused import Keys (unused-import)


Report
======
24 statements analysed.

Raw metrics
-----------

+----------+-------+------+---------+-----------+
|type      |number |%     |previous |difference |
+==========+=======+======+=========+===========+
|code      |35     |79.55 |35       |=          |
+----------+-------+------+---------+-----------+
|docstring |0      |0.00  |0        |=          |
+----------+-------+------+---------+-----------+
|comment   |1      |2.27  |1        |=          |
+----------+-------+------+---------+-----------+
|empty     |8      |18.18 |8        |=          |
+----------+-------+------+---------+-----------+



**other output omitted **
```

PyLint --version:

```
No config file found, using default configuration
pylint 1.1.0, 
astroid 1.0.1, common 0.61.0
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
```

my runtime:

[image: myruntime]

Comment: So if you run "/usr/bin/pylint /home/devnull/pyworkspace/soup/test1.py" it works as expected? Are you expecting to be using python 3? Do you have python 2 installed? What version of python is Eclipse configured to use?

Comment: yes I would like to lint python 3. I have python 2 also installed, I use python 3 in eclipse. i added the output and my output from pylint --version. Maybe my pylint version is to old ? may i should not install pylint over apt-get and use pip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the same problem. I have python 2.7 and python 3.4 Installed pylint using

```
apt-get install pylint
```

and I got the same error as you.

Then I instaled

```
apt-get install pylint3
```

and updated the location of the pylint executable to

```
/usr/bin/pylint3
```

and it worked.

When you install modules you will need to target your specific python major version number.

I had to do the same for numpy and scipy etc.